# Named Entity Recognition For Product Names Of Clothes

Tags: regex, nlp, text-mining, spacy, email-parsing

I am trying to extract product names from a plain text, the problem with product names is that they don't have a specific pattern and I don't want to give the algorithm a set of data that has fixed names I want it to be generic.

I'm looking for a way to make it detect the product names as an Entity.

Any help please?

Here's an example of the text

> Order dispatched Your new clothes are on their way. Track your
>   delivery with Royal Mail: VB 9593 7366 0GB
>
> Order Details
>
> Men's Dark Navy Jersey Cotton Lounge Shorts Size: XL
>
> £45.00
>
> Men's Navy Cotton Jersey Lounge Pants Size: XL
>
> £60.00
>
> Delivery £0.00
>
> Total £95.00

I want to extract

> Men's Navy Cotton Jersey Lounge 
>   and 
>   Men's Dark Navy Jersey Cotton Lounge Shorts

Another example

> Your order summary Delivery between 18/11/2019 and 19/11/2019 Shipping
>   from O' adidas Lxcon sneakers £80.96 Delivery between 18/11/2019 and
>   19/11/2019 Shipping from BOUTIQUE ANTONIA MARCELO BURLON COUNTY OF
>   MILAN Confidencial striped swimsuit £97.58 Shipping Total Payment
>   method £20.00 £153.90 VISA

I want to extract

> adidas Lxcon sneakers

And

> MARCELO BURLON COUNTY OF MILAN

For your information this text is an email of orders and I have a lot of different patterns of emails.

Comment: What did you tried and not worked? If all order ar like this text, tou can may be catch patterns that comme after `order details` and befor the word `size`  and all string between £xx.xx then clean  `size: xl`. It’s not easy to handle sure

Comment: Look I added another example which doesn't have the same pattern as the first and I still have other different patterns, I don't want to create a pattern for each example I want something generic

Comment: If one is open for training a model, then an approach is to train a Conditional Random Fields algorithm.

Comment: @SidharthMacherla can I train a CRF with Spacy??? How much data do I need???

Comment: [Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/nlp-guide-conditional-random-fields-text-classification/) is an article that explains the same.